# Return custom message from a NestJS custom validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have a custom validator in my NestJS application that checks if an input string is valid CSS. To do this, I'm using `postcss.parse` to parse the string and check its validity. If the input is not valid CSS, `postcss.parse` throws a `CssSyntaxError` with details about the failure.

My goal is to display this error message in the UI as an error. However, I cannot find any resource that explains how to customize message from `defaultMessage` based on an error in `validate` function.

```
import { IsOptional, IsString, Validate } from 'class-validator';
import { ValidatorConstraint, ValidatorConstraintInterface } from 'class-validator';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import postcss from 'postcss';

@ValidatorConstraint({ async: true })
@Injectable()
export class CssValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  async validate(value: string) {
    try {

      const result = await postcss.parse(value);

      return true;

    } catch (error) {
      if (error.name === 'CssSyntaxError') {
        console.log(error.reason);  // eg: Unclosed comments
        
      }
    }
    return false;

  }

  defaultMessage() {
    return 'Invalid CSS provided'; // I want to customize this message based on error caught in above `validate` function
  }
}

export class CustomStylesCreateDto {
  @Validate(CssValidator)
  styles?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`defaultMessage()` function in `ValidatorConstraintInterface` only returning string. So basically to return custom error message string that depends on your validation logic you can declare **private variable** inside the `ValidatorConstraintInterface` class.

Example:

```
export class CssValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  private validationErrors: string[] = []; // private variable to hold errors

  async validate(value: string) {
    try {
      const result = await postcss.parse(value);

      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.name === "CssSyntaxError") {
        this.validationErrors.push(error.message); // push your error
        return false;
      }
    }
    return false;
   }

 defaultMessage() {
   // return default message if no custom error message is provided
   if (this.validationErrors.length === 0) {
     return "Invalid CSS provided";
   }

   // return custom error message
   return this.validationErrors.join(", ");
   }
 }
```